# Self-Validating Model Not Returning Errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a self validating model. When the form is submitted, the errors don't show up in the view underneath their corresponding textboxes. However, it only shows up in the ValidationSummary. I want it to show up underneath each textbox. Thanks.

Model:

```
public class BankAccount : IValidatableObject
{    
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; } 

  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    List<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
    {
      errors.Add(new ValidationResult("Enter valid lastname por favor."));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    {
      errors.Add(new ValidationResult("Enter valid firstname por favor."));
    }

    return errors;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      BankAccount oBankAccount = new BankAccount();
      return View("Home", oBankAccount);
    }


    [HttpPost]    
    public ActionResult Index(BankAccount oBankAccount)
    {
      return View("Home", oBankAccount);
    }
  }
```

View:

```
@model BankAccountApp.Models.BankAccount
@{
  Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>    

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
      @Html.ValidationSummary()

      // FirstName TextBox
      <span>FirstName: </span> 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

      <br />

      // LastName TextBox
      <span>LastName: </span> 
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, null, new { @class = "formErrors" })    

      <input type="submit" value="submit me" />  
    }

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you mark your `LastName` property with the `[Required(ErrorMessage="Test")]` attribute?

Comment: When I add the required attribute as you say, it displays "Test" next to it, if nothing was filled in. If something was filled in, then nothing shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change you method as following

```
  public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
  {   
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
    {
      yield return new ValidationResult("Enter valid lastname por favor", new[] { "LastName" });
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
    {
      yield return new ValidationResult("Enter valid firstname por favor.", new[] { "FirstName" });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks a bunch! Could you explain why what I had wasn't working and this one works?

Comment: If you don't provide the field name as a second parameter to the ValidationResult constructor, then the runtime associates the result with the model, and not a specific property on the model. Html.ValidationMessageFor is looking for results associated with the property in the expression, and doesn't find the model related results.

Comment: @saltProgrammer legendary  Scott Allen (OdeToCode) has answered ur question in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your method for making a validated model has been obsoleted. I would suggest moving to the DataAnnotations method for making validation on your models. That seems to work.

Comment: What makes you say it's obsoleted? Has it been deprecated? Thanks.